# Page scrollbar disappears after using jquery.remove()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a page with a table, where user can request to delete each row. If user decides to do so, a query is sent to the server to delete the content, and if the query is successful, I remove the row from the table using a javascript code like this:

```
function removeItem(Id) {
  $('#removeItemBtn' + Id).button('loading');
  $.post( "../api/item/remove/", {Id: Id})
      .done(function( data ) {
        $('#removeItemModal' + Id).modal('hide')
        $('#removeItemBtn' + Id).button('reset');
        $('#ItemRow' + Id).remove();
    }).fail(function() {
        // error handling goes here ...
    });
}
```

Where id is the ID of the row user just deleted. This works, and I can see the row is removed, but the side-effect is that the scrollbar on the page also disappears, and I can't scroll in the whole page any more, until I refresh the page again!

I can't find any clue why this is happening. I have only tested it on Chrome 42/Ubuntu 12.04 so far. Any idea what is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: can you post some more code?

Comment: Try testing it in Firefox as well to rule out a browser issue. One obvious observation is that the scollbars may disappear if the content fits on the page, but this is not it? It is likely that something else is applying some CSS like 'overflow: hide' when handling the AJAX (?) response. Maybe make a simple HTML page, no AJAX/server calls, just a button that removes a row and see if that works as you expect.

Comment: @sveatlo I added some more code.

Comment: @Kenny you are right, the content does not fit the page, but still scrollbars disappear. I tried it on Firefox 37 and the same issue happened. I can't say CSS is not modified 100%, but I am not explicitly doing it.

Comment: Some modal plugins set `overflow: hidden` on the body to prevent the user from scrolling, while the modal is open. So it's possible that the issue comes from the model and not from `.remove()`. You could check for this. What modal jQuery plugin are you using?

Comment: @kramsee I am using bootstrap, which works just fine, after I dismiss the modal (not deleting the row) it works just OK. If I approve removal of the row, the jQuery is used to find the elements (as shown in the code) and then the problem happens

Comment: ok, that's strange. Can you reproduce the problem with a jsfiddle? It's quite hard for me to reproduce your problem wihtout the context. :-/

Comment: Try commenting $('#removeItemModal' + Id).modal('hide'). Modal popup CSS is the culprit it seems.

Comment: i think forcing a redraw could work. can you try this?